# create roles authentication in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create roles for authentication purpose.
I've already created two types of users in my database(I am not using code first to generate database). One is "Administrator", and one is "User".

```
namespace DataAccessLayer
{

    public class DAL : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>().ToTable("tblAdministrator");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("tblUser");
        }

        public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Could anyone give me some suggestions about how to create roles for these two type of users? 
After adding roles

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to study a little time about **asp.net identity**, it's designed to solve all common problems about membership in modern app. You can manage in a few minutes claims, roles, and external providers identity as Facebook / Twitter / google and much more

- ASP.NET Identity can be used with all of the ASP.NET frameworks, such as ASP.NET MVC, Web Forms, Web Pages, Web API, and SignalR.
- ASP.NET Identity can be used when you are building web, phone, store, or hybrid applications.

[Start here on asp.net site](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, because I am new to asp.net mvc, I should loop up some tutorials and articles about this.